# pass an expression to aggregate_key

Tags: r

I can easily do:

```
library(tsibble)
tourism %>% 
  aggregate_key(Purpose * (State / Region), Trips = sum(Trips))
```

suppose instead I have

```
string <- 'Purpose * (State / Region)'
```

and would like to do:

```
tourism %>% 
  aggregate_key(some_function(string) , Trips = sum(Trips))
```

what `some_function` could be?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

We could use `parse_expr`

```
aggregate_key(tourism, .spec = !!rlang::parse_expr(string), Trips = sum(Trips))
# A tsibble: 34,000 x 5 [1Q]
# Key:       Purpose, State, Region [425]
#   Quarter Purpose      State        Region        Trips
#     <qtr> <chr*>       <chr*>       <chr*>        <dbl>
# 1 1998 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 23182.
# 2 1998 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20323.
# 3 1998 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19827.
# 4 1998 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20830.
# 5 1999 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22087.
# 6 1999 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 21458.
# 7 1999 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19914.
# 8 1999 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20028.
# 9 2000 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22339.
#10 2000 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19941.
# … with 33,990 more rows
```

---

Or using the pipe `%>%`

```
tourism %>%
    aggregate_key( .spec = !!rlang::parse_expr(string), Trips = sum(Trips))
```

---

Or construct an expression with `glue` and `parse`

```
eval(parse(text = glue::glue('tourism %>% aggregate_key({string}, Trips = sum(Trips))')))
# A tsibble: 34,000 x 5 [1Q]
# Key:       Purpose, State, Region [425]
   Quarter Purpose      State        Region        Trips
     <qtr> <chr*>       <chr*>       <chr*>        <dbl>
 1 1998 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 23182.
 2 1998 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20323.
 3 1998 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19827.
 4 1998 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20830.
 5 1999 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22087.
 6 1999 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 21458.
 7 1999 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19914.
 8 1999 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20028.
 9 2000 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22339.
10 2000 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19941.
# … with 33,990 more rows
```

Comment: it does not seem to work 

```
R> library(tsibble)
R> string <- 'Purpose * (State / Region)'
R> tourism %>% 
+   aggregate_key(as.formula(string), Trips = sum(Trips))

Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` column `as.formula(string)`.
ℹ `as.formula(string) = agg_vec(`as.formula(string)`)`.
x object 'as.formula(string)' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: fabletools::aggregate_key

Comment: Thanks for your help but `eval parse` was supposed  to be the extreme option.  
I am looking for a way to work with fable within a standard evaluation frame

Comment: @Andrea Ok, I added the `parse_expr`.  Hope it works

Comment: Thanks @akrun thsi is exactly what I was looking for. I should definitively study rlang better